# ¿Cómo incluir una condicional en el WHERE solo si un JOIN tiene algo?

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito ayuda para realizar el siguiente query en MySQL, estoy juntando dos tablas con un `LEFT JOIN` para arrojar resultados en caso de que la segunda tabla no contenga información.

```
SELECT
  e.emp_id AS "empresa_id",
  et.idioma_id AS "idioma"
FROM empresa as e
LEFT JOIN empresa_translate as et
  on et.emp_id = e.emp_id
WHERE
  replace(replace(e.emp_nombre,'z','s'),'h','')
  LIKE replace(replace('%NOMBRE%','z','s'),'h','');
```

Esto obtiene los resultados sin importar que la tabla `empresa_translate` tenga algún registro asociado con el id, sin embargo necesito implementar la siguiente lógica a lo que ya tengo.

Si es que existe algún registro en la tabla `empresa_translate` asociado a este id filtra los resultados para mostrar sólo los que tengan un `et.idioma_id = 1`.

```
SELECT
  e.emp_id AS "empresa_id",
  et.idioma_id AS "idioma"
FROM empresa as e
LEFT JOIN empresa_translate as et
  on et.emp_id = e.emp_id
WHERE
  replace(replace(e.emp_nombre,'z','s'),'h','')
  LIKE replace(replace('%NOMBRE%','z','s'),'h','')
  AND et.idioma_id = 1;
```

El problema de hacerlo de esta manera es que no arroja ningún resultado. ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de hacer esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  e.emp_id AS "empresa_id",
    et.idioma_id AS "idioma"
    FROM empresa as e
    LEFT JOIN empresa_translate as et
        on et.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE   replace(replace(e.emp_nombre,'z','s'),'h','')
        LIKE replace(replace('%NOMBRE%','z','s'),'h','')
        AND (
            ( et.emp_id IS NOT NULL AND et.idioma_id = 1)
            OR
            ( et.emp_id IS NULL)
        )
```

Básicamente son dos condiciones a revisar:

1. Si tienes una fila relacionada en `empresa_translate`, pedimos además que `et.idioma_id = 1`
2. Sino, traer las filas que no tengan relación:  `et.emp_id IS NULL`

O bien la forma más compacta

```
 AND (
        et.emp_id IS NULL OR ifnull(et.idioma_id,0) = 1
     )
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Funciona perfecto